# how to move up the values within each group in R

Tags: r, dataset

I need to shift valid values to the top the of dataframe withing each `id`. Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 itemid = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
                 values = c(1,NA,0,NA,NA,0,1,NA,0,NA))
    
df
   id itemid values
1   1      1      1
2   1      2     NA
3   1      3      0
4   2      1     NA
5   2      2     NA
6   2      3      0
7   3      1      1
8   3      2     NA
9   3      3      0
10  3      4     NA
```

excluding the id column, when there is a missing value in `values` column, I want to shift all values aligned to the top for each `id`.

How can I get this desired dataset below?

```
df1
   id itemid values
1   1      1      1
2   1      2      0
3   1      3     NA
4   2      1      0
5   2      2     NA
6   2      3     NA
7   3      1      1
8   3      2      0
9   3      3     NA
10  3      4     NA
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you can `arrange` by whether `values` is missing or not (which will put those at the bottom).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(id, is.na(values))
```

**Output**

```
      id itemid values
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1      1      1
 2     1      3      0
 3     1      2     NA
 4     2      3      0
 5     2      1     NA
 6     2      2     NA
 7     3      1      1
 8     3      3      0
 9     3      2     NA
10     3      4     NA
```

---

Or, if you wish to retain the same order for `itemid` and other columns, you can use `mutate` to specifically order columns of interest (like `values`). Other answers provide good solutions, such as @Santiago and @ThomasIsCoding. If you have multiple columns of interest to move `NA` to the bottom per group, you can also try:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = values, ~values[order(is.na(.))]))
```

where the .cols argument would contain the columns to transform and reorder independently.

**Output**

```
      id itemid values
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1      1      1
 2     1      2      0
 3     1      3     NA
 4     2      1      0
 5     2      2     NA
 6     2      3     NA
 7     3      1      1
 8     3      2      0
 9     3      3     NA
10     3      4     NA
```

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I was just looking at this! Thanks for the comment - corrected.

Comment: But doing this the order of `itemid` is lost. Compare with the desired output in the question.

Answer (score 3):

We can try `ave` + `order`

```
> transform(df,  values = ave(values, id, FUN = function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]))
   id itemid values
1   1      1      1
2   1      2      0
3   1      3     NA
4   2      1      0
5   2      2     NA
6   2      3     NA
7   3      1      1
8   3      2      0
9   3      3     NA
10  3      4     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, values := values[order(is.na(values))], id][]
#>     id itemid values
#>  1:  1      1      1
#>  2:  1      2      0
#>  3:  1      3     NA
#>  4:  2      1      0
#>  5:  2      2     NA
#>  6:  2      3     NA
#>  7:  3      1      1
#>  8:  3      2      0
#>  9:  3      3     NA
#> 10:  3      4     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd define a function that does what you want and then group by `id`:

```r
completed_first <- function(x) {
  completed <- x[!is.na(x)]
  length(completed) <- length(x)
  completed
}

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    values = completed_first(values)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#       id itemid values
#    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1     1      1      1
#  2     1      2      0
#  3     1      3     NA
#  4     2      1      0
#  5     2      2     NA
#  6     2      3     NA
#  7     3      1      1
#  8     3      2      0
#  9     3      3     NA
# 10     3      4     NA
```

(This method preserves the order of `itemid`.)

---

Or building upon **ThomasIsCoding**'s answer:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    values = values[order(is.na(values))]
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 3
#       id itemid values
#    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1     1      1      1
#  2     1      2      0
#  3     1      3     NA
#  4     2      1      0
#  5     2      2     NA
#  6     2      3     NA
#  7     3      1      1
#  8     3      2      0
#  9     3      3     NA
# 10     3      4     NA
```